# Permutations containing a given subsequence

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients

Let $f(n)$ denote the number of $4n$-long strings formed from $2n$ a's and $2n$ b's, such that the string contains, as a (possibly non-consecutive) subsequence, a pattern containing $n$ a's and $n$ b's.  (Note that $f(n)$ doesn't depend on the pattern, so two possible patterns would be
$$\overbrace{\strut a\cdots a}^{n\textrm{ times}}\, \overbrace{\strut b\cdots b}^{n\textrm{ times}}\quad\textrm{ or }\quad \overbrace{abab\cdots ab}^{n \textrm{ pairs}}.)$$

In the notation of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248381/probability-of-getting-a-to-k-on-single-scan-of-shuffled-deck/1252059#1252059), this number is $\left[\begin{array}{c}2n,2n\\n,n\end{array}\right]$.

By using the first pattern, and summing over the number of b's which occur before the $n$-th a, we find that
$$(*)\quad f(n)= \sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n+r-1}{r}\binom{3n-r}{n}.$$

The resulting sequence is $$1, 5, 53, 662, 8885, 124130, 1778966, 25947612, 383358645, \ldots$$
which appears in OEIS as [A036910](http://oeis.org/A036910), where we find a nice closed form for the $n$-th term:
$$(**)\quad\frac12\left(\binom{4n}{2n}+\binom{2n}{n}^2\right).$$

The WZ-pair machinery should prove that $(*)$ and $(**)$ are equal, so that's not a concern.  My question: is there a straightforward combinatorial argument which gives the count $(**)$ directly (i.e., not as the result of evaluating a sum)?

The closed form suggests the cycle index formula for an involution, but I'm not seeing an answer along those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a direct counting argument.  Let $S$ be the set of permutations of the word $a^{2n}b^{2n}$.  For any word $w\in S$, and for any pattern $p$, write $w\vdash p$ to mean that $w$ contains $p$ as a subsequence.

Set $A=\{w\in S\mid w\vdash a^nb^n\}$ and
$B=\{w\in S\mid w\vdash b^n a^n\}=\{w\in S\mid \bar w\vdash a^n b^n\}$; note
$$|A|=|B|=\left[\matrix{2n,2n\\n,n}\right].$$
The key observation is that $A\cup B=S$; that is, for any $w\in S$, at least one of $\{w,\bar w\}$ contains $a^n b^n$ as a subsequence.  (To see this, let $a_i$ and $b_i$ be the position of the $i$-th occurrence of $a$ and $b$ in $w$ respectively.  If $w\not\vdash a^nb^n$, then there are at most $n-1$ $b$'s after the $n$-th $a$, so $b_{n+1}<a_n$, hence $w\vdash b^{n+1}a^{n+1}$ and in particular $\bar w\vdash a^nb^n$.)
Hence
$$2\left[\matrix{2n,2n\\n,n}\right]=|A|+|B|=|A\cup B|+|A\cap B|=|S|+|A\cap B|.$$
We claim $A\cap B$ consists precisely of the words in which both the first and last half contain exactly $n$ $a$'s and $n$ $b$'s. (To see this, note that $w\in A\cap B$ iff $b_{n+1}>a_n \textrm{ and } a_{n+1}>b_n$, so $b_{n+1}\ge 2n+1$ and $a_{n+1}\ge 2n+1$.  This implies that the second half of $w$ contains at least $n$ $a$'s and $n$ $b$'s, so the characterization follows.)  It follows that $|A\cap B|={\binom{2n}n}^2$.  Since $|S|=\binom{4n}{2n}$, we're done.

*Remark.* This argument can be cast in terms of the cycle index formula as well.  Define an action of ${\Bbb Z}_2$ on $S$ via the involution $\iota:S\to S$ sending $w\mapsto w$ if $w\in A\cap B$, and $w\mapsto\bar w$ otherwise.  The observation above says that each ${\Bbb Z}_2$-orbit contains exactly one $w$ such that $w\vdash a^nb^n$.  Then the number of ${\Bbb Z}_2$-orbits on $S$ is
$$\left[\matrix{2n,2n\\n,n}\right]=
   \frac12\left(|\textrm{Fix}(\textrm{id})|+|\textrm{Fix}(\iota)|\right)
   =\frac12\left(|S|+|A\cap B|\right).
$$

Answer (score 3):

The  WZ machinery  is very  powerful but  it is  also an  incentive to
evaluate these sums manually e.g.  by using the Egorychev method which
I hope will make for a rewarding read.

Suppose we are trying to evaluate
$$\sum_{r=0}^n {r+n-1\choose n-1} {3n-r\choose n}.$$

Put
$${3n-r\choose n}
=  \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{3n-r}}{w^{n+1}} \; dw$$

and furthermore introduce
$$[[0\le r \le n]]
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^n}{z^{r+1}} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{(z-1)z^{r+1}} \; dz.$$

This second integral controls the range  so that we may extend the sum
to infinity to get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{3n}}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{(z-1)z}
\sum_{r=0}^\infty {r+n-1\choose n-1} 
\frac{1}{z^r (1+w)^r}
\; dz \; dw.$$

This simplifies to
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{3n}}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{(z-1)z}
\frac{1}{(1-1/z/(1+w))^n}
\; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{3n}}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{(z-1)z}
\frac{z^n}{(z-1/(1+w))^n}
\; dz \; dw.$$

Computing the contributions from the  pole at $z=1/(1+w)$ (there is no
pole at zero anymore) we get two pieces, call them $A$ and $B$, $A$ is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{3n}}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{z^{n-1}}{(z-1/(1+w))^n}
\; dz \; dw.$$

We have
$$\frac{1}{1-z}
= \frac{1}{1-1/(w+1)-(z-1/(w+1))}
= \frac{1}{w/(w+1)-(z-1/(w+1))}
\\ = \frac{1}{w/(w+1)}\frac{1}{1-(z-1/(1+w))/(w/(w+1))}
= \frac{w+1}{w}\frac{1}{1-(z-1/(1+w))(w+1)/w}.$$

This gives for the inner integral from $A$
$$\frac{w+1}{w} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\left(\sum_{q\ge 0} (z-1/(1+w))^q \frac{(w+1)^q}{w^q}\right)
\\ \times
\left(\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose p} (z-1/(1+w))^p
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{n-1-p}}\right)
\frac{1}{(z-1/(1+w))^n}
\; dz.$$

Computing the residue we get
$$\frac{w+1}{w} \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose p} 
\frac{(1+w)^{n-1-p}}{w^{n-1-p}}
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{n-1-p}}
\\ = \frac{w+1}{w}
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose p} \frac{1}{w^{n-1-p}}
\\ = \frac{w+1}{w} \left(1+\frac{1}{w}\right)^{n-1}
= \frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^n}.$$

Substituting this into $A$ we get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{3n}}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^n} \; dw
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{4n}}{w^{2n+1}} 
\; dw = {4n\choose 2n}.$$

Returning to $B$ which is
$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{3n}}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{z^{2n}}{(z-1/(1+w))^n}
\; dz \; dw.$$

we get for the inner integral
$$\frac{w+1}{w} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\left(\sum_{q\ge 0} (z-1/(1+w))^q \frac{(w+1)^q}{w^q}\right)
\\ \times
\left(\sum_{p=0}^{2n} {2n\choose p} (z-1/(1+w))^p
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{2n-p}}\right)
\frac{1}{(z-1/(1+w))^n}
\; dz.$$

Computing the residue we get
$$\frac{w+1}{w} \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose p} 
\frac{(1+w)^{n-1-p}}{w^{n-1-p}}
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{2n-p}}
\\ = \frac{w+1}{w}
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{n+1} \times w^{n-1}}
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose p} w^p
\\ = \frac{1}{(1+w)^n w^n}
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose p} w^p.$$

Substituting this into $B$ we get
$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{3n}}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{(1+w)^n w^n}
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose p} w^p 
\; dw
\\ = - \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{2n}}{w^{2n+1}}
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose p} w^p \; dw.$$

This is
$$-\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose p} {2n\choose 2n-p}.$$
By symmetry this evaluates to
$$-\frac{1}{2}\left(-{2n\choose n}^2
+ \sum_{p=0}^{2n} {2n\choose p} {2n\choose 2n-p}\right).$$

This last sum is 
$$ [x^{2n}] (1+x)^{2n} (1+x)^{2n}
= [x^{2n}] (1+x)^{4n} = {4n\choose 2n}.$$

so we finally have for piece $B$ the value
$$-\frac{1}{2}\left(-{2n\choose n}^2
+ {4n\choose 2n}\right).$$

We may now conclude, collecting  the contributions from $A$ and $B$ to
obtain

$${4n\choose 2n}
-\frac{1}{2}\left(-{2n\choose n}^2
+ {4n\choose 2n}\right)
= \frac{1}{2}
\left({4n\choose 2n} + {2n\choose n}^2\right).$$

Comment: Beautiful!  But it just makes me want a direct combinatorial argument that much more...

Answer (score 3):

In the following we consider without loss of generality the string $a^nb^n$ of length $2n$, which is a shorthand for
\begin{align*}
\overbrace{\strut a\cdots a}^{n\textrm{ times}}\, \overbrace{\strut b\cdots b}^{n\textrm{ times}}
\end{align*}

> We show the number of strings of length $4n$ with  $2n$ $a$'s and  $2n$ $b$'s  containing the (not  necessarily  contiguous) subsequence $a^nb^n$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{2}\left[\binom{4n}{2n}+\binom{2n}{n}^2\right] \tag{1}
> \end{align*}

The number of possibilities to select $2n$ positions out of $4n$ to place the string $a^nb^n$ is
\begin{align*}
\binom{4n}{2n}
\end{align*}
The other $2n$ positions can be freely placed by the other $n$ a's and $n$ b's.

> **First step:** In order to count each valid string not more than once, we have to respect symmetries.
>
> Therefore we count only those patterns out of the $\binom{4n}{2n}$ strings where we place *no* $b's$  at the left half. In other words, we count those patterns with less or equal $n$ positions selected on the left half.
>
> Since we have $n$ $a$'s and $n$ $b$'s *in reserve*, we can always fill positions on the left half with $b$'s from the reserve accordingly, correspondingly to the patterns out of the $\binom{4n}{2n}$ selections with $k>n$ positions on the left side.
>
> This leads *nearly* to
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{2}\binom{4n}{2n}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> The formula (2) correctly counts the cases with $0\leq k <n$ $a$'s at the left half, but not the case with $k=n$ $a's$.
>
> **Second step:** We have additionally the special case with $k=n$ $a$'s to consider.
>
> In all other cases, whenever we consider $0\leq k<n$ $a$'s on the left hand, we have the pendant of $n$ $a$'s and $n-k$ $b$'s on the left hand giving $\binom{2n}{k}=\binom{2n}{n-k}$ possibilities. But, in case of $k=n$ $a$'s we have to 
>   count each occurrence with $n$ $a$'s on the left side without cut them in halves. The number of all valid strings with exactly $n$ $a$'s at the left side and $n$ $b$'s at the right side is
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{2n}{n}^2
> \end{align*}
>   Since half of  these possibilities is already counted by (2) we have to add the other half $\frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}^2$ and so we finally see that the claim (1) is valid.

**Note:** The combinatorial interpretation is based upon the binomial identity
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}^2=\binom{4n}{2n}
\end{align*}
and the symmetry
\begin{align*}
\binom{4n}{2n}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}\binom{2n}{2n-k}+\binom{2n}{n}^2+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}\binom{2n}{2n-k}\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}^2+\binom{2n}{n}^2\\
\end{align*}
from which
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}^2&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\binom{4n}{2n}-\binom{2n}{n}^2\right]\\
\text{and}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k}^2&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\binom{4n}{2n}+\binom{2n}{n}^2\right]\\
\end{align*}
follow.

Comment: @Tad: Thanks for granting the bounty! Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

**Addendum.** The calculation in the other answer is  not quite rigorous in that the infinite series  that appears does  not converge in a  neighborhood of zero for $z.$ This can be fixed by using a different Iverson bracket.

Suppose as before that we are trying to evaluate
$$S = \sum_{r=0}^n {r+n-1\choose n-1} {3n-r\choose n}$$

which is
$$S_2-S_1  = 
\sum_{r=0}^{2n} {r+n-1\choose n-1} {3n-r\choose n}
- \sum_{r=n+1}^{2n} {r+n-1\choose n-1} {3n-r\choose n}.$$

Start by evaluating $S_2.$

Put
$${3n-r\choose n}
=  \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{w^{2n-r+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{n+1}} \; dw.$$

and use the following Iverson bracket 
$$[[0\le r \le 2n]]
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{z^{r}}{z^{2n+1}}\frac{1}{1-z} \; dz.$$

This second integral controls the range  so that we may extend the sum
to infinity to get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{2n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\sum_{r=0}^\infty {r+n-1\choose n-1}
z^r w^r \; dz \; dw.$$

This simplifies to
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{2n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{(1-wz)^n}
\; dz \; dw.$$

We evaluate the inner integral using the fact that the residues at the
three poles sum  to zero. The residue at $z=0$ is  the sum $S_2$ which
we are trying to compute. The residue at $z=1$ yields

$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{2n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{2n+1}} \; dw
= -{2n+2n\choose 2n} = -{4n\choose 2n}.$$

For the residue at $z=1/w$ re-write the integral as follows:
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{3n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{(z-1/w)^n}
\; dz \; dw.$$

We require a derivative which we compute using Leibniz' rule:
$$\frac{1}{(n-1)!} 
\left(\frac{1}{z^{2n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{(n-1)}
\\ = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q}
(-1)^q \frac{(2n+q)!}{(2n)! \times z^{2n+1+q}}
\frac{(n-1-q)!}{(1-z)^{1+n-1-q}}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n+q\choose 2n}
(-1)^q \frac{1}{z^{2n+1+q}}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-q}}.$$

Evaluate at $z=1/w$ to get

$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n+q\choose 2n}
(-1)^q w^{2n+1+q}
\frac{w^{n-q}}{(w-1)^{n-q}}.$$

Substitute this back into the integral in $w$ to obtain
$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n+q\choose 2n}
(-1)^q
\frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{3n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{n+1}}
\frac{w^{3n+1}}{(w-1)^{n-q}} \; dw 
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n+q\choose 2n}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{2n-q+1}} \; dw
= 0.$$

We have shown that
$$S_2 = {4n\choose 2n}.$$

Continuing with $S_1$ we see that
$$S_1 = \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}
{r+2n\choose n-1} {2n-1-r\choose n}
= \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}
{r+2n\choose n-1} {2n-1-r\choose n-1-r}.$$

For this sum no Iverson bracket is needed as the second binomial
coefficient controls the range via the following integral:

$${2n-1-r\choose n-1-r}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{2n-1-r}}{w^{n-r}} \; dw.$$

Furthermore introduce
$${r+2n\choose n-1} 
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{r+2n}}{z^n} \; dz.$$

This gives the integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{2n-1}}{w^{n}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^n}
\sum_{r\ge 0} \frac{w^r (1+z)^r}{(1+w)^r}
\; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{2n-1}}{w^{n}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^n}
\frac{1}{1-w(1+z)/(1+w)}
\; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{2n}}{w^{n}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^n}
\frac{1}{1+w-w(1+z)}
\; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{2n}}{w^{n}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^n}
\frac{1}{1-wz}
\; dz \; dw.$$

Extracting the inner residue we obtain
$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose n-1-q} w^q$$
which yields
$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose n-1-q} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{2n}}{w^{n-q}} \; dw
\\= \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose n-1-q} {2n\choose n-1-q}.$$

This is
$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose q}^2$$
which may be evaluated by inspection as in the other answer, and collecting the contributions from $S_2$ and $S_1$ we once more obtain

$$\frac{1}{2}
\left({4n\choose 2n} + {2n\choose n}^2\right).$$

**Remark.** To be fully rigorous we must also show that the residue at
infinity of

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{(1-wz)^n} \; dz$$

is zero. Recall the formula for the residue at infinity
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty} h(z)
= \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} 
\left[-\frac{1}{z^2} h\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right]$$

which in this case yields
$$-\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} 
\frac{1}{z^2} z^{2n+1} \frac{1}{1-1/z} \frac{1}{(1-w/z)^n}
\\ = -\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} 
z^{2n} \frac{1}{z-1} \frac{1}{(1-w/z)^n}
\\ = -\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} 
z^{3n} \frac{1}{z-1} \frac{1}{(z-w)^n}$$
which is zero by inspection.